# Preview report in SSRS without reloading data

Tags: reporting-services

**My system**

Windows 7, 64 bit

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2013. Version 12.0.40629.00 Update 5

**The question**

I'm just getting started with SSRS, and I'm swicthing alot between Design and Preview mode.

It frustrates me that this is taking a bit long, particularly when I'm only adjusting the sizes of graphs and tables etc. Is there any way to preview the report without reloading the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to preview without running the queries. This is because if it doesn't run a query it (and you) don't know what data to expect and what the report should therefore look like.

Imagine if you were returning a textbox colour from your query for example. Without running the query the report would have no idea what colour the textbox should be.

To speed up the time to generate the preview is it possible to run the query against less data so it executes faster?   For example against a sample set of data from your database which is only 10% of the total rows from your production db?

Comment: Thank you for a swift answer. I'm going to give it a go with your suggestion of reducing number of rows for a "development" query.